# How to find VSCode default NodeJS binary location?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed VSCode on Windows 10 without installing NodeJS.

I created an simple extension with an **extension.js** file contents:

```
const activate = () => {
    console.log(process.version)
}

module.exports = { activate }
```

After restart VSCode, I see the output `'v12.8.1'` in Developer Tools console.

So where is the default NodeJS binary location? I have searched in VSCode installed folder and in AppData also but was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code doesn't include a seperate copy of node; it uses electron with the [`RUN_AS_NODE` flag](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/environment-variables#electron_run_as_node) to run extensions in a node environment

Comment: Can I use it to run `npm` and install "npm packages"?

Comment: No, it does not include npm, only the node runtime